# How to correctly center and resize an image?

Tags: html, css

I am aware that there are plenty of question identical to mine, but it seems that I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to make a website, and for now the layout I'm looking for is a logo at the very top followed by the name of the brand and then under it a navigation bar. I did the nav bar first, but when trying to put the image in, I couldn't resize it, let alone center it with text. Can somebody help me achieve what I'm trying to do, or at least explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

P.S. Here is my code.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: sticky;
}

li{
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.logo img{
    float: center;
    width: 80;
    height: 80;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>QPlugs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.PNG">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Home">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#Join">Join</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#Shop">Shop</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#About">More Info</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.S. If it helps, when I inspect the image on the page, I get [this thing here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4A5a.png)

Comment: Also, I made a mistake with the width and height, I forgot to put px, but the float: center; still doesn't work. Furthurmore, could anyone also clarify how I can put the logo AND text in the middle of the page? Thanks!

Comment: Give a with to the image and give it a `margin: auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is no* `float: center`. Instead, you can use `text-align: center;` on `.logo` (the container of the image). And you need to use the `px` unit on `width` and `height` of the image.

BTW: Since you wrote about centering image and text, I added an `h1` in my snippet which is also centered via `text-align: center`. (You could also add settings for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` if you want to change the default distance to the elements above and below)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  <title>QPlugs</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.PNG">
      </div>
      <h1>Header Text</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#Join">Join</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#Shop">Shop</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#About">More Info</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, after looking a little more into it I realized that was my problem, as for the name and the logo to be aligned, should I make two div elements, or should I make an unordered list with the two li's as the logo and the name?

Comment: I just added something to my answer which should answer that

Answer (score 0):

Use display: flex is much easier to use and flexible

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: sticky;
}

li{
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo img{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>QPlugs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.PNG">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Home">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#Join">Join</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#Shop">Shop</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#About">More Info</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```